# mysql decimal rounding

Tags: mysql, insert, decimal, rounding

I am inserting decimals into my MYSQL database but the values that end up in the DB are rounded, despite my having set the DB to DECIMAL(10,4). For example I set the discount to 6.5 and the DB records it as 7.

My query is:

```
$save = sprintf("
INSERT INTO discount
SET         am_discount = %d,
                tx_discount = '%s'
",
    $_POST['am_discount'],
    mysql_escape_string($_POST['tx_discount'])
);
```

I've tried setting the `am_discount` field to `%u` and `%f` as well, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

As I mentioned, the am_discount field in my MYSQL DB is set to `DECIMAL (10,4)` and I've also tried (10,2) and (8,2).

What am I missing?

Comment: can you show the table structure here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
$save = sprintf("INSERT INTO discount  SET am_discount = '".$_POST['am_discount']."',
                tx_discount = '".mysql_escape_string($_POST['tx_discount'])."' ");
```

Answer (score 1):

its seem to be database table column property issue, if some one can endorse me on it.

please change your table column property to "Float".

MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D). Here, “(M,D)” means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point. For example, a column defined as FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999 when displayed. MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is 999.0001.

Reference :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was under the impression FLOAT wasn't accurate. I want to use the values entered to calculate totals later on, which is why I went for DECIMAL.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a database table column property issue. Decimal is the correct column type.

For inserts into a DECIMAL or integer column, the target is an exact data type, so rounding uses “round half away from zero,” regardless of whether the value to be inserted is exact or approximate.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-rounding.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the database, actually. It's sprintf behavior for %d.

```
%d The argument is treated as an integer and presented as a (signed) decimal number.
```